# Youtube API returns 1,000,000 results everytime , its an estimated result and not the exact one. How to implement pagination for this?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I would like to add pagination to the youtube API results.
The results returned are 1,000,000 results always.

I have read about this number of results returned, It seems its an estimated number and not the exact count.

In this scenario how to implement pagination.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are currently using

Answer (score 0):

> **pageInfo.totalResults**
>
> **integer**
>
> The total number of results in the result set.Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value. In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.

Source: [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults)

[Implementation: Pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) will help you to understand how pagination works with YouTube Data API v3. The 1,000,000 value isn't a limit, however [there may be other limitations](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId). So let us know if you are still stuck.